# Primefaces, when I drop a component onto a Dashboard, I want to trigger action

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using Primefaces 5.1 and I have a dashboard where I can drop components onto it.

But, when I drop a component on I want a different component to be rendered.

Here is my dashboard, and the panel component that is cloned and dropped onto the dashboard.

```
<p:dashboard id="board"  model="#{dashboardBean.model}" binding="#{dashboardBean.dashboard}">
        <p:ajax event="reorder" listener="#{dashboardBean.handleReorder}" update="msgs" />
</p:dashboard>

<p:panel id="draggable">
    <h:outputLabel value="Drag Panel Into Dashboard"></h:outputLabel>
</p:panel>
<p:draggable for="draggable" helper="clone" dashboard="board"/>
```

Now I can trigger a capture the 'reorder' event and change the 'model' to replace it with the correct component on the java side. But the Dashboard does not get re-rendered at this point.

I can add a command button to trigger the re-render...

```
<h:commandButton value="Refresh"  action="#{dashboardManagedBean.refreshChart}"/>
```

But I want this to happen automatically.

Can anyone offer some advice please.

[image: What I see]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(comment promoted to answer)

What if you referesh the component from `handleReorder()` using this `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("foo:bar")`?